# Rails, Omniauth: NoMethodError - undefined method `persisted?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-connect

I am using the `omniauth-stripe-connect` gem and get the following error when authenticating users:

> NoMethodError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#stripe_connect
>   undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass

My Callbacks Controller Action:

```
def stripe_connect
    @user = UserProvider.find_for_stripe_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted? # here is the issue !!!
        sign_in @user, :event => :authentication
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

And my User Method:

```
def self.find_for_stripe_oauth(auth)
    user = UserProvider.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user.nil?
        user.user
    else
        registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
        unless registered_user.nil?
            user_provider = UserProvider.new
            user_provider.provider = auth.provider
            user_provider.uid = auth.uid
            user_provider.user_id = registered_user.id
            user_provider.save!

            registered_user.stripe_access_code = auth.credentials.token
            registered_user.stripe_publishable_key = auth.info.stripe_publishable_key
            registered_user.stripe_id = auth.extra.raw_info.stripe_user_id
            registered_user.skip_confirmation!
            registered_user.save!

            registered_user
        end
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `unless .. .nil?` use `if .. .present?` because it's more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_for_stripe_oauth` returns `nil` if `registered_user` is not exists. In this case `unless registered_user.nil?` returns `false` and inner block is not executed.

Move out `registered_user`, like this:

```
    registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
    unless registered_user.nil?
        user_provider = UserProvider.new
        user_provider.provider = auth.provider
        user_provider.uid = auth.uid
        user_provider.user_id = registered_user.id
        user_provider.save!

        registered_user.stripe_access_code = auth.credentials.token
        registered_user.stripe_publishable_key = auth.info.stripe_publishable_key
        registered_user.stripe_id = auth.extra.raw_info.stripe_user_id
        registered_user.skip_confirmation!
        registered_user.save!
    end

    registered_user
```